# Using a Schur complement, prove that the matrix has two double eigenvalues

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, block-matrices, skew-symmetric-matrices, schur-complement

For a skew symmetric block $n \times n$ matrix $B$, prove that matrix $M$ has two double eigenvalues.

$$ M = \begin{bmatrix} I & B \\ B & I\end{bmatrix} $$

For a proof, I was using the determinants, but got stuck as I do not know how to take into the account the skew symmetric matrices.

\begin{align}
\det(M-\lambda I) &= \det((1-\lambda)I)\det((1-\lambda)I-(1-\lambda)^{-1}BB)\\
&=(1-\lambda)^{n}\det((1-\lambda)(I-(1-\lambda)^{-2}BB))
\\
&=(1-\lambda)^{n}(1-\lambda)^{n}\det((1-\lambda)^{-2}((1-\lambda)^{2}I-BB))
\\
&=(1-\lambda)^{n}(1-\lambda)^{n}(1-\lambda)^{-2n}\det((1-\lambda)^{2}I-BB)
\\
&=\det((1-\lambda)^{2}I-BB)
\end{align}

At the last step I got stuck as I am not sure how to proceed to prove that there are two double eigenvalues.

Comment: Think of the characteristic polynomial of $B^2$.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo got it, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Following the @RodrigodeAzevedo comment, I found the solution to be:
$$
\det\left((1-\lambda)^{2}I-BB\right) \implies \det\left(B^2-\tilde{\lambda}^2I\right)
$$
$$
\det\left(B^2-\tilde{\lambda}^2I\right) = \det\left(B-\tilde{\lambda}I\right)\det\left(B+\tilde{\lambda}I\right)
$$
considering the skew symmetric matrix
$$
B=-B^{\mathrm T}
$$
$$
\det\left(B^{\mathrm T}+\tilde{\lambda}I\right)\det\left(B+\tilde{\lambda}I\right)
$$
And because the eigenvalues of a matrix and its transpose are the same, we have double eigenvalues.